# Help with tikz hyperreal line drawing

Tags: tikz-pgf, draw

I want to draw something like this:

[image]

with tikz, I know how to lines but I don't know how to draw the curves. Can someone help me?

Comment: Welcome! It is very easy do add the curves if the rest is provided, otherwise anyone trying to answer this needs to start from scratch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an attempt to recreate the complete screen shot but to give you an example for how to draw such curves.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[pics/cline/.style={code={
 \foreach \X/\Y [count=\Z] in {#1}
 {\draw ({\X},-0.1) -- ({\X},0.1) 
  node[text depth=0.25ex,above] (-n-\Z){$\Y$};
 \ifnum\Z=1
  \path ({\X},0)  coordinate[alias=aux-first] (-p-1);
 \else
  \path ({\X},0)  coordinate[alias=aux-last] (-p-\Z);
 \fi}
 \draw[shorten <=-1mm,shorten >=-1mm] (aux-first) -- (aux-last);
 }}]
 \path pic[xscale=3] (A) {cline={-1/-\omega,0/0,0.5/{\omega/2},1/\omega,2/{2\omega},%
    {sqrt(7)}/\sqrt{7},3/{3\omega}}}
    (0,-2)pic[cyan] (B) {cline={-4/-4,-3/-3,-2/-2,-1/-1,0/0,1/1,2/2,3/3}};
 \draw[cyan] (B-n-2.north west) to[bend right=15] ([yshift=-1mm]A-p-2)
  (B-n-8.north east) to[bend left=15] ([yshift=-1mm]A-p-2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]